# Rails 5: distinct values in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, distinct

I have working solution where users who belong to current_user companies can be found.

In */controllers/users_controller.r*b I have this:

```
def index
@companies = current_user.companies.includes(:users)
@users = @companies.map(&:users).flatten
end
```

In console I can get this (current_user ID=2):

```
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Company Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies" INNER JOIN "accounts" ON "companies"."id" = "accounts"."company_id" WHERE "accounts"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 2]]
Account Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."company_id" IN (14, 15, 16)
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IN (1, 2)
```

Users: 1, 2 is my desired result.

*/models/user.rb*

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
has_many :accounts, dependent: :destroy
has_many :companies, through: :accounts
```

*/models/account.rb*

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :company
belongs_to :user
accepts_nested_attributes_for :company, :user
```

*/models/company.rb*

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
has_many :accounts, dependent: :destroy
has_many :users, through: :accounts
accepts_nested_attributes_for :accounts, :users
```

In view at the moment I have this: `<%= render @users %>`  with this related partial:

```
<li>
   <%= link_to user.name, user %>
</li>
```

**How to get unique values of users?** At the moment I get multiple values of users if one user is in several companies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@users = @companies.map(&:users).flatten.uniq` should do I believe

Also building on @idej's answer you could also do

```
@users = User.joins(:accounts).where("accounts.company_id IN (?)", current_user.companies.pluck(:id)).uniq
```

which should do the same thing and be more efficient

Comment: Thank you, however this does not work as I get this error: `undefined method map for nil:NilClass Did you mean? tap`  In current solution in console example I see those two user ID, however I cannot print it out.

Comment: that would mean the `@companies` variable is not initialized. You could do it without that if you don't need it `current_user.companies.includes(:users).map(&:users).flatten.uniq`

Comment: Thank you, your edited 2nd suggestion works like charm and seems to be the most effective :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `uniq` method to remove duplicates from array

```
@companies = current_user.companies
@users = @companies.map(&:users).flatten.uniq
```

Or you can do it with active record creating queries like

```
@companies = current_user.companies
@users = User.joins(:accounts).where("accounts.company_id in (?)", @companies.map(&:id)).uniq
```

Comment: Thank you, however for first suggestion I get this error: `undefined method map for nil:NilClass Did you mean? tap` For second I get this one `QLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.company_id: SELECT DISTINCT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."company_id" IN (14, 15, 16)`  In Accounts table I have two columns: company_id, user_id

Comment: In first solution you should initialize `@company` like you did `@companies = current_user.companies.includes(:users)` and then `@users = @companies.map(&:users).flatten.uniq`. The second approach not working because I miss hat you have relation through accounts table.

Comment: Thank you, your edited suggestion works, though it seems to me a bit less effective than @Rocco solution. Anyway Rails community the best and thank you + I'm upvoting your answer as well.

Comment: Your query with uniq is highly inefficient and does a lot of n+1 queries. You should remove it, or provide a better solution without queries e.g @users = User.where(company_id: @companies.pluck(:company_id))